# API to retrieve images from within an image or pdf

Tags: node.js, image-processing, ocr, image-recognition, image-extraction

I am looking for a way to extract images from within another image. For example:
[image]

Here is a picture taken of a paper. It includes text, an image of a camera, and an image of a qr code. Is there an API that can possibly extract those two(camera and qr code) from this larger image and separate them into their own individual images. I know this is doable with the text(OCR), but I need to find some way to do Image Recognition if that even exists. For now, I cant find any reference to doing this besides extracting images from pdf's, which none of those softwares have the capability to extract them from a non-perfect pdf.

Price for the API(node.js prefered, but i can adapt to use any language) is not a big concern, I'm just not sure this is even possible to due without programming a legitable artificial intelligence using machine learning, which I would no doubt cause a global internet shutdown from breaking everything if I attempted to do so.

Anyway, any suggestions would be great and much appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT: the images aren't always those, it can be an image of anything, from potatoes to flags

Comment: Adobe Acrobat does this perfectly - you just click Edit PDF and it OCRs pictures and even fonts.

Comment: Supsayan, thanks for the suggestion. Would adobe work on images converted to pdfs though? So essentially blurry pdf's that are slanted and imperfect. From all the other pdf image extractors I tested, none of them could achieve the task. I haven't tested adobe yet, so ill try that.

Comment: asking for recommendations is off-topic. [help/on-topic]

Comment: Ah, alright. I'll not do this again. One last thing: Do you have any reccomendations on a site I can ask for reccomendations?

Answer (score 1):

For the QR code, you can simply use a QR code scanner library and convert the output back into a QR code. As for the camera, you are going to need an image recognition service like [Google Cloud Vision](https://cloud.google.com/vision) or train your own neural network with something like TensorFlow to recognize pictures of cameras.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I didn't know google cloud vision could also recognize images. I'll look into that.

Comment: No problem. By the way, if the only thing your image contains will be some text, a camera, and a QR code you might eliminate the text and the QR code, leaving you with only the camera. This way, you won't have to deal with extracting the camera alone.

Comment: Hmmm, didn't think of that.  Is this also a feature in cloud vision?

Comment: I apologize, I am unable to locate where in the API I am capable of detecting and isolating images. The only function available(maybe its in a category here that I am just unable it can do it) are: label detection, text detection, saf search, facial detection, celebrity detection, landmark detection, logo detection, image properties, crop hints, web detection, and object localization.

Answer (score 0):

QR detectors abound around the web and some are on github but for single objects you could try hotpot API https://hotpot.ai/docs/api
your code example linked into https://hotpot.ai/remove-background

[image]

for striping back you may need a secondary autocrop task

[image]
[image]